# how do I publish a new ros node or package?

Tags: ros, package, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've written a small ROS package and uploaded the source to a repository on github.

It's a package to provide some interfaces between ROS and the SIG EVO car racing championship simulation.

I thought I would then be able to then publish my package so that it would show up on http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php somewhere.

I had a look on ros.org for how to do this, but can't see it.  Am I on the right track?  Or should I add my node to an approved repository?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9959/how-do-i-publish-a-new-ros-node-or-package?/) by [SeanPayne](https://answers.ros.org/users/276/seanpayne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2011-05-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a new package which you would like to announce and get indexed please email the ros-users mailing list to announce it and we will add it to our documentation indexer.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3